# Button with 2 lines of text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

I would like to have a button with 2 lines of text and if text is longer than 2 lines and size of maxWidth, the text should fit into the button borders.

```
android:maxLines="2"
```

doesn't work

Any tips?

Comment: please put more code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write Multiline Text on Button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699776/write-multiline-text-on-button-in-android)

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103776/how-can-i-display-multiple-lines-of-text-on-a-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="2"
    ../>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Android normal `Button` widget not having as such functionality.

You have to use the android new library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
```

[Here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/) is the reference.

@[Gabriele Mariotti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953175/2196176) Already define the one way to use of it.